# Какую версию PyPDF2 на python лучше изучить?

Tags: python

Всем привет. Я только начинаю изучать python. На данный момент я читаю книгу Дэна Бейдера "Знакомство с python". В этой книге рассказывается про библиотеку PyPDF2 старой версии, а именно 1.2.6, а последняя вышедшая версия этой библиотеки 3.0.1. Так вот вопрос, как мне поступить? Изучить по книге версию 1.2.6 или изучить версию 3.0.1 по ресурсам из интернета. Если лучше выбрать второй вариант можете скинуть ссылку чтобы изучить эту версию?

Answer (score 0):

> скинуть ссылку чтобы изучить эту версию?

https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/

1. Уже есть версия 4
2. Абсолютно все модули Python надо брать с https://pypi.org

Comment: _Абсолютно все_ — нет, некоторые надо брать с гитхаба, потому что на pypi их просто нет)

Comment: @Глеб - "некоторые надо брать с гитхаба," - Вы советуете так поступать человеку, который "Я только начинаю изучать python" ?!

Comment: Нет, я просто комментирую, это абстрактное замечание)